# Sending file with ajax to server

Tags: php, ajax, yii

Here is my view:

```
<?php $modelupload=new Upload; ?>
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'upload-upload',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'onsubmit'=>"return false;",
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ),
)); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($modelupload,'New name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($modelupload,'Name'); ?>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($modelupload,'File'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->fileField($modelupload,'Extra'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($modelupload,'Description'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($modelupload,'Description'); ?>
</div>

<?php echo CHtml::Button('Upload',array('onclick'=>'upload();')); ?>


<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function upload(){
    var data=new FormData($("#upload-upload")[0]);
    var extra={data1:"some text i want to attach",data2:"more text"};
    data={data:data,extra:extra};
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("site/upload"); ?>',
        data:{"command":data},
        dataType:"json",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function successFunc(arr){
             alert(arr['text']);
        },
        error:function errorFunc(){
             alert("Something went wrong.");
        }
    })
}

</script>
```

When I check $_POST['command'] on server, it says that its not set and the whole array $_POST is empty... It works fine without file uploading, but with the file and multipart/form-data I cant make it work...

How do I upload a file + attach information from other form fields + attach my own information? I have tried a few things and read other people questions, but I cant get the result I want.

Comment: if in extra var data is not dependent ... u can use two hidden filds for that... and also dont use onclick function ... use afterValidate by making clientValidation set to true and in clientOptions make afterValidate function where use same technique call upload() function... and return false to avoid redirecting (for synchronise form submission) ... and check in console (chrome) what data is being passed..

Answer (score 0):

**May be you can solve problem by this..**

```
 <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'dimages-form',
 //'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
 'enableClientValidation'=>true,
 'clientOptions'=>array(
 'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
 'afterValidate' => 'js:function(form, data, hasError) { 
                          if(hasError) {

                               alert("validation failed");

                            }
                            else 
                            {

                                  upload(form, data, hasError);
                                 //return true ;  for synchronize form submission not ajax
                            }
                    }',
                ),
 'htmlOptions'=>array('role'=>"form",'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')));  
?>
```

**put extra value you want as hidden fields .... and that should follow the NAME combination of form like this**

```
<input type="hidden" name="ModelName[hiddenFiels1]" id="ModelName_hiddenFiels1" value="desired data" />
<input type="hidden" name="ModelName[hiddenFiels2]" id="ModelName_hiddenFiels2" value="desired data"  />
```

**pass hidden fields as many you want... and now upload function...**

```
function upload(){
var data = new FormData(form[0]);
 $.ajax({

    "type":"POST",
    "url":form.attr('action'),
    "data": data,
    "async": false,
    "success":function(data){

           alert('success');

    },
    "cache": false,
    "contentType": false,
    "processData": false,
 });

}
```

may be better practise of doing an ajax call can help you to solve ur proble...

and at server side... retrive data

```
if(isset($_POST['ModelName']))  or print_r($_POST);
```

and use console.... or Simple REST Client to debugg...

Answer (score -1):

I wrote my own XMLHttpRequest instead of using ajax and it worked! I can access my data inside php with

```
$arr=explode(',',$_POST['command']);
```

and my file with

```
$file=CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('File');
```

... I guess this is even better then using ajax, but still I would like to know how to make it work with ajax...

```
function upload(){        
    var data=new FormData();
    var input=document.getElementById('Upload_Extra');
    var command=[$("#Upload_Name").val(),$("#Upload_Description").val(),"Some text I want to attach","more text"];
    data.append("command",command);
    data.append('File',input.files[0]);
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST','<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("admin/upload");?>',true);
    xhr.onload=function(){
        if (this.status==200){
            var resp=JSON.parse(this.response);
            alert(resp.text);
        };
    };
    xhr.onerror=function(){
        alert("Something went wrong.");
    }
    xhr.send(data);
}
```